# Using mysql_fetch_array to retrieve a field value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following PHP code to retrieve a name from a table matching an ID:

```
$qry = "SELECT league_name FROM Leagues where league_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_LEAGUE_ID']."'";
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
$leaguename = $row['league_name'];
```

I know that SESS_LEAGUE_ID is correct as I can output it to a variable and see it, however when I try and grab the name that matches the ID from the table Leagues I get nothing back.

$leaguename is always blank. I've checked the database and there should definitely be some text returned. The league_name field is a varchar type.

I know it's something simple that I'm not doing but I can't think what!

Comment: Please do not use mysql* functions in new code, it is deprecated. Try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @zjd Next time, include a link to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388)

Comment: Thanks for the advice on mysql. I'll read up on mysqli and PDO and try to implement them on my site as an alternative :-)

Comment: If I do a replace on 'mysql' for 'mysqli' using CTRL+F are there any functions that might stop working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to execute the statement

```
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Perfect! Works as intended. Thanks for the quick response.